# Query Data from Adobe into R

Tags: r, api, metrics, adobe-analytics, segment

I'm trying to query data from adobe analytics into R to run some modelling. I have achieved to get into the report suite however however I have problems in:

1. retrieving metrics alphanumeric like this metric_id=cm976_6214c0d05066f5066579e56e (calculated metric). I get all the metric with `GetMetrics('reportsuite')`, I create the vectors to call with

`used_metrics = c('visits'#,'cm976_6214c0d05066f5066579e56e'`
`)`
`used_elements = c('page',#'mobiledevicetype'`
`)`
`used_segments = c('s976_620e3f9b4a896668e759b407'#, 's976_5cd557f3cd96c85fd552ac1e'`
`)`

however then with
`mydata <- QueueDataWarehouse(reportsuite.id = "reportsuite", date.from = "2022-02-01", date.to   = "2022-02-28", metrics = used_metrics, elements = used_elements, segment.id = used_segments, date.granularity = "day", interval.seconds = 10, max.attempts = 200, enqueueOnly = F)`

I receive the below errror
ERROR:

> metric_id_invalid  -  Metric "cm976_6214c0d05066f5066579e56e" not found

despite like metrics like visits or event* work just fine

2. My second problem is when apply segments with `segment.id = used_segments`
   the call doesn't finalize and going into 500 until my last attempt

   (max.attempt=200)

   > [1] "Requesting URL attempt #200"
   > [1] 500

all the filters have format alphanumeric like the example. is it possible this format is messing with the query? I don't find a solution if anyone could help would be appreciated.
thanks,

I have tried different metrics and segments
I'm expecting to recall adobe data into Rstudio using RSiteCatalyst package

Answer (score 0):

For your first issue, you have a `#` in your `used_metrics`, `used_segments`, and `used_elements` vectors, removing those should fix the issue.

For your second issue, I believe that the same issue with the `#` in your vectors is what's causing the segments to not work until your last.